# Visual Studio "15" Preview uninstall

Tags: visual-studio, uninstallation, logfile, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to install VS "15" Preview 5, I have launched the new installer and now it's saying that I must uninstall previous version (Preview 4).
When I click on remove button the uninstall process fails and this is the error on log file:

```
2016-10-05T23:20:59 : Verbose : Getting installed product. [installerId: SetupEngine, installationId: 9554cc50, productId: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Enterprise]

2016-10-05T23:20:59 : Verbose : Calling SetupEngine.Installer.UninstallProduct. [installPath: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VS15Preview']

2016-10-05T23:20:59 : Error : Failed to get installed product. [installerId: SetupEngine, installationId: 9554cc50, productId: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Enterprise, error: Sequence contains more than one element at    at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.CommonExtensions.GetProduct(IInstance instance, Boolean installedOnly)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstalledProductsProviderService.CorrectChannelInformation(Instance instance)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstalledProductsProviderService.GetInstalledProductForPathImpl(String path)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstalledProductsProviderService.GetInstalledProductImpl(InstalledProductSummary productSummary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstalledProductsProviderService.GetInstalledProduct(InstalledProductSummary productSummary)]

2016-10-05T23:20:59 : Verbose : SetupEngine.Installer.UninstallProduct reported error.  [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element at    at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.CommonExtensions.GetProduct(IInstance instance, Boolean installedOnly)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.CacheRepository.GetAvailablePackages()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Uninstall(CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallerService.UninstallProductImpl(InstalledProductSummary productSummary, TelemetryContext telemetryContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallerService.UninstallProduct(InstalledProductSummary productSummary, TelemetryContext telemetryContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)]

2016-10-05T23:21:00 : Verbose : Getting installed product summaries. [installerId: SetupEngine]

2016-10-05T23:21:00 : Verbose : Getting product summaries. [installerId: SetupEngine]
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must uninstall all previous releases of Visual Studio ‘15’ before you try preview 5, and you can uninstall the previous versions through the Visual Studio Installer or use ‘Uninstall a program’ from Control Panel. When the Visual Studio Installer cannot work, we can manually remove Visual Studio as below:

1. Close the Visual Studio Installer
2. Delete folder %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\
3. Delete the Visual Studio folder installation folder (normally under %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\VS15Preview)
4. After that, the previous installation is removed. Start Visual Studio Installer of Visual Studio Preview ‘15’ again to install 
   For more detail information about the VS preview ‘15’ installation, you can see [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/visual-studio-15-FAQ).

Comment: Note that the installer for RC version will apparently do a "cleanup". 

From the 2017 FAQ: During installation of Visual Studio 2017 RC, a cleaning tool will automatically be run on your machine that will detect artifacts from a prior preview installation and then remove them. This process will ensure a "clean machine" state before the RC is installed. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-FAQ

Comment: @GrahamMc There is currently a bug related to this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/3280/vs-2017-installation-does-not-uninstall-vs-15-prev.html